# :Error al Conectar PhpMyAdmin con XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Soy nuevo usando Xampp y al instalarlo todo estaba bien pero al intentar entrar al php Myadmin me dio el siguiente error
Error
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

No se estableció la conexión: los parámetros están incorrectos.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión.
 La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión.
 phpMyAdmin intentó conectarse con el servidor MySQL, y el servidor rechazó esta conexión. Deberá revisar el host, nombre de usuario y contraseña en config.inc.php y asegurarse que corresponden con la información provista por el administrador del servidor MySQL.

Comment: Es posible que tengas que ejecutar xampp en modo administrador

Comment: el problema puede ser que no le especificas el puerto, mira prueba así:
$host = "127.0.0.1:3307"; (En tu caso quizás sea 3306 el puerto) Suerte.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Sí que funciona, aunque luego a la hora de iniciar sesión me da un error parecido. ~ El servidor MySQL no autorizó su acceso ~ ~ mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) ~ Osea, me aparece la ventana para iniciar sesión pero cuando intento entrar me salen esos errores.

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como dice el mensaje hay que revisar el archivo config.inc.php que se encuentra en la siguiente dirección C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin. Ten en cuenta que la unidad "C" en mi caso es la raiz del sistema operativo, asi tienes que adecuarla a tu unidad correspondiente. A continuación abrimos el archivo y nos centramos en la parte como se muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la linea que dice `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` entre las comillas simples especificamos las password que pusimos al user correspondiente es decir la misma que habiamos puesto en el formulario anterior cuando podiamos entrar en phpmyadmin. Además también es necesario que cambies el valor de "config" por "cookie" en `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'.` Finalmente ya con esto deberia estar solucionado.

Comment: Excelente Genio, no te puedo dar puntuación porque soy nueva pero me salvaste