# Como arreglo este error de PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Quiero ingresar a phpMyadmin y no puedo por culpa de este error me pueden ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has mirado el contenido del archivo que te indica config.inc.php y has revisado que sean datos correctos?

Comment: revisa la siguiente [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363803/error-al-conectar-phpmyadmin-con-xampp) , seguramente te servirá.